# Infinite wire with alternating current and conducting half-plane

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

I'm kinda confused about the following. Suppose I have a harmonic current-density of
$$j=j_0 e^{i\omega t}=I_0 e^{i\omega t} \, \delta(x)\delta(y-h) \, e_z$$
parallel to the $z$-axis (at $x=0$ and $y=h>0$) and for $y\leq 0$ the domain is conducting with conductivity $\sigma>0$. How do I determine the electric field of this configuration? I figured I can use the general solution for the domain $y>0$
$$A=\frac{\mu I_0}{4\pi} \, e_z \int {\rm d}^3 r' \, \frac{e^{i\omega/c \left(ct-\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}\right)}}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}} \, \delta(x') \delta(y'-h) \\
=\frac{\mu I_0}{4\pi} \, e_z \, e^{i\omega t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm d} z' \, \frac{e^{-i\omega/c\sqrt{x^2+(y-h)^2+z'^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-h)^2+z'^2}} \\
=\frac{\mu I_0}{2\pi} \, e_z \, e^{i\omega t} \, {\rm K}_0\left( i\omega/c \sqrt{x^2+(y-h)^2} \right)$$
where the integral from $z'=0$ to $\infty$ is a representation of the modified Bessel-K function. Non-trivially (I think) we have ${\rm K}_0(ix)=-\frac\pi 2 ({\rm Y}_0(x) + i{\rm J}_0(x))$ where the contribution $J_0$ is actually just a homogenous remnant. Therefore we can write
$$A=-\frac{\mu I_0}{4} \, e_z \, e^{i\omega t} \, {\rm Y}_0\left( \omega/c \sqrt{x^2+(y-h)^2} \right) \tag{0}$$
at least for $y>0$.
We can similarly arrive at this result by considering the domain $y>0$ away from the source, where the wave-equation
$$\left( \frac{1}{c^2} \partial_t^2 - \Delta\right)A=0 \tag{1}$$
becomes under the assumption $A\sim e^{i\omega t}$ and cylindrical (coordinates $\rho,\varphi,z$) symmetry if we - for a moment - put the source at the origin
$$\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \rho \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} + k^2\right)A = 0$$
with $k=\omega/c$ and $\varphi,z$-independence. With $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$, the solution for the $z$ component is given by
$$A_z=c_1 {\rm J}_0(k\rho) + c_2 {\rm Y}_0(k\rho)$$
with complex constants $c_1,c_2$. The two constants within $c_1$ are determined by the initial condition (which I do not worry about), since this solution (finite at the origin) is a true homogenous solution. The other constant is determined by integrating $B=\nabla \times A$ along a closed curve and then using Stokes and the Maxwell-Equation $$\nabla \times B=\mu j + \mu \epsilon \dot{E}\, .$$ Its value $-\mu I_0/4$ coincides with (0). Furthermore we have the relation $E=-\dot{A}$, since there are no charges. Shifting back the origin of the source to $(0,h)$, I now consider the domain $y\leq 0$, where we have the material equation $$j=\sigma E \, .$$
Under the assumption $|\dot{E}|/|E| \ll \sigma/\epsilon$, we can neglect the displacement current and arrive at the diffusion equation
$$\left(\mu\sigma \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \Delta\right)A = 0 \, ,$$
with general solution
$$A = \frac{\mu\sigma}{4\pi t} \int {\rm d}x'{\rm d}y' \, e^{-\frac{\mu\sigma}{4t} \left( (x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 \right)} \, A_0$$
where $A_0$ is the initial condition, but I'm not even sure how to use it. In particular I guess I need to enforce the continuity $$E_{\parallel,1}=E_{\parallel,2}$$
at $y=0$ for the two solutions $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: not for the faint-hearted but here is a reference that might help from the man himself -  Ronold King: The Theory of LINEAR ANTENNAS with Charts and Tables for Practical Applications, Chapter VIII, Section 19, "HORIZONTAL DIPOLES OVER A CONDUCTING EARTH"